# In Scala, Is tuple syntax part of language itself or an implicit constructor call on TupleN?

Tags: scala

```
val tuple3 = Tuple3(1, 2, 3)
```

It's `apply` of `Tuple3`. But why is this compilable:

```
val tuple = (1, 2, 3)
```

Is that `Tuple3.apply` called implicitly? Based on what?

Or is it a  `1.,(2,3)` call which I can't find definition of in `predef` or anywhere else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is that Tuple3.apply called implicitly? Based on what?

It isn't called *implicitly*. The `( )` syntax is simply syntactic sugar over `TupleN`. Here it's transformed into `Tuple3.apply`. It is called based on the compilers interpretation of the text, which is based on the Scala specification (see [Section 6.9, Tuples](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#tuples)):

> ### 6.9 Tuples
>
> `SimpleExpr   ::=  (' [Exprs] )'`
>
> A tuple expression `(e1,…,en)` is an alias for the class instance
>   creation `scala.TupleN(e1,…,en)`, where `n≥2`. The empty tuple `()` is the
>   unique value of type `scala.Unit`.

You can the see type tree created with `scalac -Xprint:typer` flag. This:

```
object Y {
  val tuple = (1,2,3)
}
```

Turns into:

```
package <empty> {
  object Y extends scala.AnyRef {
    def <init>(): Y.type = {
      Y.super.<init>();
      ()
    };
    private[this] val tuple: (Int, Int, Int) = scala.Tuple3.apply[Int, Int, Int](1, 2, 3);
    <stable> <accessor> def tuple: (Int, Int, Int) = Y.this.tuple
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the Scala language specification [1] you can read this:

> A tuple expression (e1,…,en) is an alias for the class instance
>   creation scala.Tuplen(e1,…,en), where n≥2. The empty tuple () is the
>   unique value of type scala.Unit.

I assume, the scalac basically substitutes all `(...)` with `Tuple(...)`

[1] http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html